# How to zip file before saving original on drive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, export-to-csv, fs

in this code I get p(file path) and can download it

```
function createCSV(){
  return mytmp.getTempDir((tmpPath) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      let p  = path.resolve(tmpPath, "snake_case_users33.csv");
      var ws = fs.createWriteStream(p);

      csv
        .write([
          {a: "a1", b: "b1"},
          {a: "a2", b: "b2"}
        ], {headers: true})
        .pipe(ws);

      resolve(p);

    });
  });
}
```

But I need to zip .csv file, either before formatting date, or at first to format .csv file, after to zip it and save on drive and get path.

at the beginning i need to create csv :

```js
let p = path.resolve(tmpPath, "snake_case_users.csv");
        var output = fs.createWriteStream(p);
        csv.write([
            {a: "a1", b: "b1"},
            {a: "a2", b: "b2"}
          ], {headers: true});

//below let zipPath = path.resolve(tmpPath, "snake_case_users.zip"); and zip
```

maybe after we could use zipPath to zip this csv somehow?

Comment: The sentence after your code is a tad confusing. Can you try to reword that?

Comment: @leigero, i'd like to zip formatted csv file and get path to download one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use archiver module.

https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver

It very easy to use and it can wrap even all folder into zip.

Here is example code to make zip from a folder

```
function archive (cb) {

  var archive = require('archiver');
  var timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
  // this self.logPath + '/archive' + timestamp + '.zip' is the path to zip file. 
  //You can use any path you like. 
  var zipPath = self.logPath + '/archive' + timestamp + '.zip'
  var output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);
  var archive = archiver('zip');

  output.on('close', function() {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');

    return cb("All ok or path to zip");
  });

  archive.on('error', function(err) {
    return cb("Error");
  });

  archive.pipe(output);
  //read directory
  var allLogs = fs.readdirSync('path to dir or to file');
  //append files to archive
  async.eachSeries(allLogs, function(fileName, callback){
      var file = path.join(self.logPath, fileName);
      archive.append(fs.createReadStream(file), { name: fileName });
      callback();
  }, function(){
      //finalize it will trigger on close event
      archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Of course you will need to change some paths, but everything else should be fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: How could i get zip file path to download this file with my zipped csv?

Comment: Check var zipPath  variable

Comment: I edited my question for you, check please. I need archive, which contains csv

Comment: When you done with creating csv...Just create read stream using pathToCSVFile then use archive.append(you read stream) and resolve on stream ends. Append API https://archiverjs.com/docs/Archiver.html#append